# Triggering of gc on Metaspace memory in java 8

Tags: java-8, garbage-collection, jvm

What condition triggers the garbage collection of Metaspace when MaxMetaspaceSize property is not set on the jvm.

Say if i close few unused classloaders there is a scope to free up the memory in the metaspace memory. My questions is does the full gc trigger the cleanup of metaspace memory or is it triggered in some other way.

Comment: Are you asking what under which conditions metaspace memory may be released or under which conditions the metaspace filling up triggers a GC? those are two different things.

Comment: since by default Metaspace in Java 8 is not limited, when does jvm understands that it need to clean up the unreferenced classes from its metaspace.

Answer (score 3):

> since by default Metaspace in Java 8 is not limited, when does jvm understands that it need to clean up the unreferenced classes from its metaspace.

Metaspace itself is not garbage-collected. But the java heap is. When `java.lang.Class` objects get collected the underlying metadata gets freed too. So in most circumstances regular GC cycles will also free up metaspace if there are any classes that are eligible for unloading.

> but want to understand when does the gc get triggered to cleanup the metaspace memory of the undeployed apps.

At the latest when the current capacity of the metaspace is full, possibly earlier when regular garbage collections unload classes.

Comment: aren't class objects stored in metaspace instead of heap space. so how does gc on heap space help clean up of meta space

Comment: no, `Class` objects are in the heap. the internal representation of the class is in metaspace.

Comment: oh yes @the8472 i may have got it wrong regarding Class Objects being stored in metaspace. My question now is on what condition does the jvm garbage collect the metaspace when MaxMetaspaceSize property is not set. If that property is set, jvm seems to use MinMetaspaceFreeRatio, MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio to trigger the gc

Comment: i don't want to set that property, instead i want the aggresive clean up of metaspace when eligible for unloading. Just wondering how to do that kind of a thing

Comment: what is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: we are running in an environment where we need to do multiple hot deploys of  apps(max 5) on a tomcat server. So the apps get undeployed and deployed with new content on a regular basis. These apps are dynamically in nature where each app can load any no. of classes. That's the reason we doesn't want to set any maxMetaspace property, but want to understand when does the gc get triggered to cleanup the metaspace memory of the undeployed apps.

Comment: in java8 metaspace is unlimited if not specified, that's the feature we want because the metaspace in our tomcat server can grow to any level. how can it determine that the metaspace is full

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's the full GC that cleans up the metaspace, specifically you should see entries like this `Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold)` after enabling verbose mode on the gc.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABFAFAE), I may just quote it here.

> -XX:MetaspaceSize=size
>   Sets the size of the allocated class metadata space that will **trigger a garbage collection the first time it is exceeded**. This threshold for a garbage collection is increased or decreased depending on the amount of metadata used. The default size **depends on the platform**.

<sub>direct quote but the emphasis is mine ;)</sub>

Might be helpful to check the answer from [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41280431/2361308).

Answer (score -3):

Pls use System.gc() or Runtime.gc()

Comment: i don't want to manually or programatically trigger the gc, i am interested to understand when does jvm actually auto trigger the gc when the property is not set

Comment: https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/